# Using arrays, is there a way to optimize this PowerShell function?

Tags: arrays, powershell, variables

I'm writing a script to mess with call center scammers
Looking for help in optimizing this script to make it as short as possible.
I have the individual messages but when creating the array I have to input each variable manually, is there a way to turn the messages themselves directly into an array so i can loop through them and not have to input them one at a time? I want to be able to add a lot more messages without having to put the variables into the array one at a time.

assistance is appreciated please and thank you

```
function MsgBox{
    [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.Windows.Forms")
    
    $msg1 = "Are all scammers as dumb as you?"
    $msg2 = "Is the pay worth being this big of a loser?"
    $msg3 = "Do your parents know what you do for a living?"
    
    New-Object -TypeName System.Collections.ArrayList
    $arrlist = [System.Collections.Arraylist]@($msg1, $msg2, $msg3)
    
    Foreach ($item in $arrlist) { 
       [System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox]::Show($item , "Scambait" , 4 , 'Question')
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can declare an [array](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_arrays?view=powershell-7.2) with all the messages either by comma separated values:

```
$msgs = 'message 1', 'message 2', 'message 3'
```

Or by using the [array sub-expression operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_arrays?view=powershell-7.2#the-array-sub-expression-operator):

```
$msgs = @(
    'message 1'
    'message 2'
    'message 3'
)
```

This would allow you to add new messages to the array easily and the rest of the code would be reduced to a single loop:

```
foreach($msg in $msgs) {
    # your code using `$msg` here
}
```

Comment: and that is 100% perfect, you are appreciated